# Share link on Google+

Tags: url, share, google-plus-one

Is it possible to share/post to Google+ without using the +1 button?

e.g. Like a normal tweet button works with a url link: http://twitter.com/share?url=httpetcetcetc

Comment: What happens when you actually click a +1 button constructed using the plusone JS API? Is that emulatable? :)

Comment: There is a planned developer API for Google+. You can signup for the details + the google group here: services.google.com/fb/forms/plusdevelopers

Comment: Also, having a <iframe> solution besides Javascript would allow to embed this button to RSS feed and such. A normal link would be best, of course.

Answer (score 113):

Yes, you can.

`https://plus.google.com/share?url=YOUR_URL_HERE`

**Edit:** It works only with [eff.org](http://eff.org).

**Edit:** As of March 2012 it works on all sites.

Documentation for this sharing method is [available on the Google Developers site](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/#sharelink).

Comment: I dont think this works. Can you tell how it works, I testing it, just showed my stream page.

Comment: it also works with google.com and stackoverflow.com.  looks to have some domain filtering on it :(

Comment: It does seem to work for me. It's just not what I wanted, unfortunately.

Comment: Note that g+ generally will only accept shares of publicly accessible pages.  The problem might be you're testing with a URL they can't ping.

Comment: @poolie There are lots of publicly accessible pages that can't be pinged (they do that on purpose, to prevent DOS/DDOS attacks). I would expect the people at Google to be aware of this. So although you may be on the right track, it likely has nothing to do with "pingability".

Comment: I don't mean an ICMP ping: obviously that would neither work reliably nor prove any particular URL exists. I mean an HTTP HEAD or GET. Last time I looked, Google would check the HTTP resource when a URL was first plus-one'd. You still cannot plus private pages.

Comment: Do you know if there's another Get PARAM to pre-populate the share text? Like twitter has ?text=Look what I'm sharing!

Comment: This link format is now documented here: https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/#sharelink

Comment: @tgkokk How to add a title to share with this url?

Comment: Its not working any more. Any body have solution for this?

Comment: Working for me in 2019

Answer (score 23):

New Google share link:
    http://plus.google.com/share?url=YOUR_URL

For secure connection:

```
https://plus.google.com/share?url=YOUR_URL
```

For Wordpress:

```
https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>
```

Answer (score 17):

Yep! Use the link:

```
https://m.google.com/app/plus/x/?v=compose&content=YOUR_TEXT
```

It's SHARE url (not used for plus one) button.

If this will not work (not for me) try this url:

```
https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/confirm?hl=ru&url=_URL_&title=_TITLE_
```

Or see this solution:

[Adding a Google Plus (one or share) link to an email newsletter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157411/adding-a-google-plus-one-or-share-link-to-an-email-newsletter)

Comment: All, the second link DOES work as a solution for the problem... in a kind of hackey (thanks entirely to Goog), way, but it seems to be the only solution for this at the time of writing. You should also take note that there is one extra variable that might make you very surprised when you first try this method. Take out the Hl=ru, which is apparently a language code to make the text in Russian.

Comment: The second link will show a page that allows you to share but it does not actually add the site to your +1 list.

Comment: this is for mobile, link below is for normal computers :)

Answer (score 7):

As of July 25, 2011, the answer is no.

I have looked through their Javascript and it seems they don't want anyone directly accessing their api for +1 at the moment.

The Javascript that does all of the work for the +1 button is here:

https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js

If you run it through a Javascript cleanup program you can tell that they have obfuscated their code with various functions that only start with letters and constantly refer back to themselves and do cryptic things.

I figure in the next couple of weeks or moths they will release a link based sharing api due to the fact that we will need this for sharing from flash and other web based formats that don't rely on pure html and js.

Comment: I figure the solution he is looking for doesn't force his users to load `plusone.js`, until they click it.

Comment: As a note I answered this right when Google Plus came out and all that was available was the "plusone.js" script. There might be newer information as Goole comes out with APIs.

Answer (score 1):

i used following links in my **wordpress** website for sharing my blogs,they work fine:

**whatsapp share** : https://wa.me/?text=(some-text)(your-link)

**facebook share**: https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=(your-link)

**linkedin share**: http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=(your-link)

**google-plus** : https://plus.google.com/share?url=(your-link)

**twitter share**: http://www.twitter.com/share?url=(your-link)

Comment: Hi, Kimia, welcome to StackOverflow! I'm curious, what happens when you click the google-plus link?

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Ali Umair"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Ali UMair is a web developer"/><meta property="og:image" content="../image" />

<a target="_blank" href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=<? echo urlencode('http://www..'); ?>"><img src="../gplus-black_icon.png" alt="" /></a>

this code will work with image text and description please put meta into head tag
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot.  Google Plus has been discontinued.  Clicking [any link](https://plus.google.com/up/?continue=https://plus.google.com/share?url%3DYOUR_URL) for any answer here brings me to this text:

> Google+ is no longer available for consumer (personal) and brand accounts
>
> From all of us on the Google+ team,
>
> thank you for making Google+ such a special place.

There is one section that reads that the product *is continued* for "G Suite," but as of Feb., 2020, the chat and social service listed for [G Suite](https://gsuite.google.com/features/) is *Hangouts*, not *Google+*.

The format `https://plus.google.com/share?url=YOUR_URL_HERE` was documented at `https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/`, but this documentation has since been removed, probably because no part of Google+ continues in development.  If you are feeling nostalgic, you can see what the API used to say with an [Archive.org link](https://web.archive.org/web/20181121010319/https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/).