# custom url for Google+ share

Tags: google-api, share, google-plus

Is there any custom Url for creating  Google+ share like in twitter and facebook?

I dont want to use the +1 button

Comment: possible duplicate of [Share link on Google+](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676658/share-link-on-google)

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the Google+ Share Link. It is now available here: https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/share/#sharelink

Example usage:

> https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://stackoverflow.com