# H.264, 720p Video Bitrate

Tags: android, ios, youtube, video-capture, h.264

Disclaimer: I know very little about Video codecs & encoding.

I'm developing an iOS and Android app that allows users to record videos. I want to be able to upload the videos to YouTube & have them play at 720p quality.

The videos I'm recording will always be less than 180 seconds, always be ~30fps and will always have audio.

1. As far as I can tell, this means I need to record at a resolution of 1280x720, then I should be good. Is this correct?
2. I'm trying to determine how large, on average, an H.264 video file will be per second of video. From my understanding, I need to know the bitrate of the videos. What will the bitrate of recorded H.264 video be on Android 2.2+, and iOS 5+? [This Android developer page](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) mentions a bitrate of "2Mbps"  for "HD" video - is that 2 Megabytes per second or 2 Megabits per second? Will that rate be the same for any recorded H.264 video?

Part of the reason I'm so confused about this is because I did a test with 4 different Android-encoded videos of different lengths, and produced the following output;

[image: File Size vs Time for Android-encoded H.264 videos]

Wtf!?

Bonus points if you can link me to some iOS developer docs detailing this information - I've searched and can't find anything.

**EDITS:**

- Possibly Related: [H.264 file size for 1 hr of HD video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701991/h-264-file-size-for-1-hr-of-hd-video)
- [This wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC) mentions that the max bitrate for level 3.1 H.264 video (1280x720 @ 30fps) is from 14000 - 17500kbps.

Comment: Understanding how video formats work would be my first go-to....

Comment: I'm trying to, believe me, but it seems to be an incredibly complex topic.

Comment: I feel you. I have been working with video specs for more than 10 years, still never been comfortable with it.

Comment: Note that YouTube does the right thing for you, so you should just provide the best quality. The rest is pretty much out of your control anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yeah, 720p stands for 1280x720. I think it is correct.
2. To define how large your video file will be, you should record at a constant bitrate(CBR), but I doubt the camera will be using CBR while VBR(variable bitrate) is more efficient.
   Mbps stands for Megabits per second.
   I doubt that the rate will be the same as I stated earlier VBR could be used.

**Edit:**
Judging from the graph, it is definitely a VBR.

Comment: The outlier in the graph turned out to be recorded at a completely different bitrate / quality. I've since been scared to hell and back by the **insanely**, can't-believe-my-eyes terrible support for video recording in the Android SDK - net result, I gave up on that project. Thanks regardless!