# Is it better to host our own live streaming server on AWS c1.xlarge or use a third-party service?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, nginx, red5, live-streaming

I have an c1.xlarge EC2 instance which according to [this](http://www.zmanda.com/blogs/?p=665) article has 100 MB/S upload and download speed.

And i would be streaming a video at 720p or 1080p from this server. I am running MongoDB, NGINX on my instance.

According to [this](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130627214516AADPSt5) article the following are the consumptions for the bandwidth

```
720p 
Bits Per Second (down): 20+ Mbps 
Bits Per Second (up): 320Kbps 
Data used per 5 minute video: 37.5MB 

1080p 
Bits Per Second (down): 20+ Mbps 
Bits Per Second (up): 320 Kbps 
Data used per 5 minute video: 62MB
```

According to [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDV)

```
Bitrate for 720p:    ~18.3 Mbit/s   
Bitrate for 1080p:   ~25 Mbit/s
```

According to [stackoverflow bitrate calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701991/h-264-file-size-for-1-hr-of-hd-video)

```
25 Mbit/s * 3,600 s/hr  =  3.125 MB/s * 3,600 s/hr  =  11,250 MB/hr  ≈  11 GB/hr
```

So for a minute it would be

```
(25 (Mbit / s)) * 1 minute = 187.5 megabytes
```

My assumption is that above mentioned calculation is on a per viewer base.

Q1. So is the following calculation correct that only 1 user can be hosted per minute ?

```
(187.5 (mb / s)) / (100 (mb / s)) = 1.87500
```

Q2. Should i stream from my own server or use a third-party. If third party then what do you recommend?

Comment: I don't use red5 but this question seems completely broad, subjective and unresearched. I would say the amount of visitors your aws instances can take on nginx fronted red5 server would be based upon your own testing. Without you doing your own testing there is no factual answer to this question

Comment: Adding to @Sammaye's comment, there's a huge number of variables here, aside from CPU power (network performance, which is medium in the case of m1.large is one). If possible, I would connect the EC2 instance to Cloudfront with a streaming distribution so that you don't have to scale EC2 machines in order to to streaming (it's going to be very expensive this way).