# Simple code to upload a video to dropbox with python

Tags: python-3.x, dropbox

I have been working at writing simple code to upload the newest video in a folder to Dropbox with python.  I almost got it working but am running into two issues.  The big issue is while the video shows up on Dropbox it cannot be played and I believe the file is corrupted when uploaded.  The other issue is that the filename is renamed which I would like to keep the filename because I added a timestamp to the name to easily record when the video was taken.
-Thanks

```
dbx.dropbox.Dropbox('EmptyKey')
allfiles = glob.glob('/home/pi/Documents/CameraFeeds/*.h264')
newestfile = max(allfiles, key=os.path.getctime)
dropbox_path = os.path.join('/*')
with open(newestfile, 'rb') as f:
    dbx.files_upload(f.read(), dropbox_path, mute=True)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.
Can you tell me what the symbol `dbx` is? I'm assuming it's some object created by some python dropbox binding. Obviously omit your API keys, but I would like to be sure.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/How-to-only-upload-newest-file-with-python-3/m-p/262839#M15346 ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the size of the videos you're trying to upload, but given a [simple calculation of filesize for video length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701991/h-264-file-size-for-1-hr-of-hd-video), it seems like you may be running into the 150MB-per-upload limit using just `dbx.files_upload()`. I think you'll have better results with the `files_upload_session_start()`, `files_upload_session_append_v2()`, and `files_upload_session_finish()` commands ([found here](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moduledoc.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_upload_session_start)).

As for the file being renamed when it gets to Dropbox, the issue is with your `dropbox_path` definition. When you call `files_upload()`, the `f.read()` argument is just the raw data to upload; the `dropbox_path` arg is the only indication of the expected filename. You'll need to include `newestfile` in your `dropbox_path` definition (be careful, though, if you're using Windows: `os.path.join` uses `\\` to join the paths, which isn't compatible with Dropbox).

Comment: I am still learning python and am having a hard time understanding the documentation, is there anything you would recommend to help me figure out what is being said there?

Comment: @kwjamesblond It's not just you; that documentation is...not straightforward. Check out the link below for code that worked for me (via Python 3.6). Basically, you start a session, sequentially upload chunks of your file (the 150MB-per-upload still applies, so I have it set to append <150MB chunks), then finish the session with the last of your data and a path to save the file. https://www.dropbox.com/s/aljw1ppv80ywm0l/dropbox_large_upload_example.py?dl=0

Comment: Hello I am still having the same issue with the code example you provided, I noticed there is no .h264 at the end of this file in Dropbox it just says binary when looking at this file.  Could this be the issue?  Also I had to lower the chunk_size to get the program to run properly.  I am using a Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian so this may factor in.

Comment: @kwjamesblond Yep, I think that's the issue. I didn't include the changes to the `dropbox_path` definition I noted in my answer. You'll want to redefine this to `dropbox_path = os.path.join('/',newestfile)` (also I think the asterisk could be confusing to Dropbox). Oh nice...yeah I imagine you'll want to let Dropbox handle a bunch of small appends since you're on a Pi.

Comment: Thanks I was able to get the original code and the one you commented with to work now, thanks a lot for the great help.